# Why did Kim act so strange after Jimmy was happy that he had impressed the panel at his appeal?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In front of the panel at his appeal for getting back his law license, he starts with reading the letter Chuck had given to Jimmy in his will but stops midway and goes off this and goes with the flow. After this, outside, Jimmy seemed to have impressed the panel and appears so happy to Kim that he did it.
My question is, why did Kim react so strangely to Jimmy's happiness that he'd been so great, even though she was happy first that Jimmy had done it?

She had a similar expression before when Jimmy mentioned that he won't be practicing law under the name McGill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jimmy was happy about how he had impressed the appeals panel, and Kim was happy for him initially, but as he went on it became apparent that he had been faking any apparent emotion regarding his brother's death.  This bothered Kim, because throughout the season she's clearly showed concern for the fact that he doesn't seem to be sad or to have mourned that event at all.

From a script for the relevant scene:

> Kim THROWS her arms around Jimmy! Smiling, laughing,
>   crying... so moved by Jimmy’s emotional performance.
>
> KIM: I knew you could do it! I knew you had it in you...
>
> JIMMY: (laughing) That felt... so good.
>
> KIM: They have to reinstate you. They just have to!
>
> JIMMY: (no kidding) Uh, yeah! God, didja see those suckers? I had them! And that one asshole at the end was actually crying? He had tears. Jesus...
>
> Jimmy’s incredulous at what he’s pulled off. **Kim pulls back a little -- what did he just say?**
>
> JIMMY: I mean, I started reading the letter, but I could just tell, I could see it on their faces it wasn’t gonna be enough, so I just kinda went off on this... flow. This energy going through me, like it was improv, or jazz!
>
> Kim doesn’t interrupt him, but just listens -- stunned that he was faking. **He fooled the board, and he fooled her, too.**
>
> JIMMY: Then I just -- pop -- sank the hook in. I had ‘em, like a pied piper leading the rats right into the river. Y’know, I could see it, I could see the Matrix. Like I was invincible. I mean, God... I can dodge bullets, baby.

Comment: The relationship between Jimmy and Kim is some of the best stuff in the show, In general the show should revolve far more around their relationship and comedic lawyering and less on drugs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @steve-o. It became clear to me now why Kim appeared so strange at that moment,

Comment: @morbo I agree.  The show is fantastic as-is, and I understand that they want to keep the "Breaking Bad feel" since its a spin-off show, but I think I would've liked it more if this show stayed focused on Jimmy and his lawyering antics.

Comment: I saw it then as Kim realizing this about Jimmy’s nature, that he’s never going to go legit even this past situation was a fake-out, and why his brother Chuck had it in for him all that time. He really was a sleezy two-bit con man. She had been fooled too and maybe she needed to stop investing so much emotion into this guy.